# How to show loader while loading data from new room persistence library and have callbacks like failure or success

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to use room for my local db and my problem is that my first screen of app show the list of devices saved in room library, but room does't provide any callback like success or failure so how you guys deal with that?, also how can I show a loader while loading the data from room as I can't  work on ui from a thread until it runs on ui thread which is not recommended by room.

```
private void getDevices(){
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            devicesList =
            AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getActivity()).deviceDao().getAllDevices();
            devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Room Database does support Asynchronous queries —queries that return
>   instances of LiveData or Flowable—are exempt from this rule because
>   they asynchronously run the query on a background thread when needed.

For example, instead of returning raw data, you can use something like these:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from user where id = :id LIMIT 1")
    public LiveData<User> loadUserById(int id);
}
```

or

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from user where id = :id LIMIT 1")
    public Flowable<User> loadUserById(int id);
}
```

By using `Flowable`, you can listen to the callback to show/hide the progress dialog like this:

```
AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getActivity()).deviceDao().getAllDevices()
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe((Consumer<Subscription>) subscription -> {
                    // do something when subscribe
                    // show progress here
                })
                .doOnTerminate((Action) () -> {
                    // do something when success or fail
                    // hide progress here
                })
                .subscribe(device -> {
                    // load data success
                }, throwable -> {
                    // do when error
                });
```

---

**Reactive queries with RxJava**

Room provides the following support for return values of RxJava2 types:

> @Query methods: Room supports return values of type Publisher,
>   Flowable, and Observable. @Insert, @Update, and @Delete methods: Room
>   2.1.0 and higher supports return values of type Completable, Single, and Maybe.

To use this functionality, include the latest version of the rxjava2 artifact in your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
app/build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha02'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but when I am trying to use the same approach for delete query it doesn't seem be working I am trying to get int in return type but it's giving me compile error that delectation methods whether returns null or integer, any idea?

Comment: For that case, using Completable.frromCallable should be a good choice